# Understanding the meaning of stifling

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

One of the meanings of *stifling* in a Google search was "feel oppressed."

> 1. (of heat, air, or a room) very hot and causing difficulties in breathing; suffocating.
>    ‘stifling heat’
> 2. Making one feel constrained or oppressed.
>    ‘the stifling formality of her family life’
>
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/stifling)

Surprisingly I can't find this definition in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stifling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cambridge Dictionary definition for the second meaning says the same thing in different words.

If you are constrained you are restricted in what you can do or prevented from doing as you wish.

> adjective (NO AIR)
> extremely hot and unpleasant:
> *I can't bear this stifling humidity.
>
> Several hundred people were crammed into the stifling room.*
>
> adjective (PREVENT HAPPENING)
> *preventing something from happening:
>
> stifling bureaucracy*